# How compare values from two tables and insert if they match

Tags: mysql, pdo

i have 3 tables

1. cat

   - id (int)
   - category (varchar)
2. subcat

   - id (int)
   - category (id from category database int)
   - sub_category (varchar)
3. product

   - id (int)
   - p_name (varchar)
   - category (varchar)
   - category_id (int)
   - sub_category (varchar)
   - sub_category_id (id)

i need to  check if cat.category == product.category and subcat.sub_category 
 == product.sub_category and then insert ids from cat and subcat to products category_id, sub_category_id

```
SELECT p.*, c.category AS category_name, s.sub_category AS subcategory_name
                                        FROM product AS p
                                        LEFT JOIN subcat AS s ON p.sub_category = s.sub_category 
                                        LEFT JOIN cat AS c ON p.category = c.category
```

Comment: _i have 3 databases..._ Did you mean "tables"?.....what queries have you been trying so far? post it here

Comment: _i coudn't find solution..._ Oh! there are tons of examples out there

Comment: You want to search for "how to join tables"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looking to you schema

seems you are looking for an update for table products category_id, sub_category_id columns  based on the value of category and subcategory

you could use an update with joins

```
update product p 
inner join subcat AS s ON p.sub_category = s.sub_category 
inner join cat AS c ON p.category = c.category 
set p.category_id = c.id, 
    p.sub_category_id = s.id
```